# Dynamically generate HTML table - accessing 2 dimensional lists of objects from Jinja/Flask/Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, calendar

I am trying to generate a dynamic calendar (for an employee scheduling web app). Currently using python/flask. Currently I generate an HTML table with info passed to a jinja template. It iterates over each cell and prints passed data.

I have tried making a two dimensional matrix (which will represent the x and y axes on my HTML table). I then want to populate each 'cell' on the matrix with an object which will have whatever properties I might want to retrieve for each cell (e.g. ID to find when clicked on, text to display, multiple others that I might add)

Each row of cells gets populated with a loop
e.g.

1. position [0][0] empty / filler text
2. position [1-22][0] sequential dates
3. position [0][1-xxx] shows a shift (from database lookup) - xxx will depend on number of available shift types in database
4. position [1-22][1] contain calendar cell objects with info (e.g. which staff member is doing the shift on the same row on the date for this column

The table_matrix is passed to the jinja template which then iterates over the same data and uses it to make the HTML table.

I am a beginner in both python and coding, so excuse me if I've done something obviously stupid!

If there is a better way to solve the overall problem I am happy to hear it too.

Thanks!

Create table matrix:

```
    table_matrix = [[0 for x in range(table_columns)] for y in range(table_rows)]
```

Sequential dates for row 0: ("start_day" is just dummy text while I troubleshoot)

```
    for each in range(21)[1:]:  #slicing - starts from array 1 not 0
        table_matrix[0][each] = CalendarTableCell
        table_matrix[0][each].cell_text = "start_day"
```

Pass to Jinja template as table_matrix=table_matrix

When I do this (manually assigned to "ROSTER") in jinja it seems to work fine

```
    {{ table_matrix[0][0].cell_text }}
```

When I loop through the table matrix in jinja I get

```
<class 'app.models.CalendarTableCell'>
```

or lists of [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ]

I've tried looping with

```
    {% for each in table_matrix %}
        <td>{{ table_matrix[0][each] }}</td>
    <% endfor %}
```

and

```
    {% for each in table_matrix %}
        <td>{{ table_matrix[0][each].cell_text }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

And also tried with

```
    {% for sublist in table_matrix %}
        {% for item in sublist %}
           {{ item }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

(and also tried with item.cell_text and item[0]/item[1]/item[3]...)

I expect to find the same data I passed in - preferably an object with several variables accessible (if I can't do that, it will add a lot of complexity or I need to come up with a new structure)

Comment: shouldn't be `table_matrix[0][each] = CalendarTableCell()` with `()` at the end ?

Comment: instead of `range(21)[1:]` you can use `range(1, 21)`

Comment: first you fill matrix with zeros, later you use `range(21)[1:]` skip first row when you put `CalendarTableCell`, and later you display full matrix so you should get `[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ]` for first row - it is correct result for first row.

Comment: maybe use `for` loop and `print()` before you send matrix to template - to see what you really have in matrix.

Comment: if I `print() table_matrix[][].cell_text` I get the "start_day" I expect just after I create it -so it looks fine when it gets passed to the Jinja template. I just can't figure out what to do to access it from the template

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't be table_matrix[0][each] = CalendarTableCell() with () at the end ?

Thanks to furas (I can't find where I can acknowledge the correct answer? No option that I can see)

It was as simple as having the () after the CalendarTableCell - works fine now.

Comment: That was a comment and not an answer. You can only accept answers, which is why you're not seeing the button.